# Issues with groupby

Tags: dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook, julia

Anyone know why I keep getting grouby not defined?[error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLmGl.png

```
rename!(df_,Symbol("climate change") => :)
rename!(df_,:Month => :date)
df_[!,:Δ] = [missing;log.(df_.[2:end]) - log.(df_.[1:end-1])]
df_ = df_[completecases(df_),:]
first(df_,6)
df_sp[!,:r] = [missing;df_sp[2:end,:closeadj]./df_sp[1:end-1,:closeadj].-1]
firstobs = [true;df_sp.ticker[2:end] .!= df_sp.ticker[1:end-1]]
df_sp = df_sp[.!firstobs,:]
df_sp = df_sp[completecases(df_sp),:]
df_m[!,:rₘ] = [missing;df_m[2:end,:closeadj]./df_m[1:end-1,:closeadj].-1]
df_m = df_m[completecases(df_m),:]
df_sp = leftjoin(df_sp,df_m[:,[:date,:rₘ]];on=:date)
df_sp = leftjoin(df_sp,df_[:,[:date,:Δ]];on=:date)
first(df_sp,6)
gdat = grouby(df_sp,:ticker)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple typo - you need `groupby`, not `grouby` (note the `p`)

Also you can use the `ShiftedArrays` package to compute log returns as

```
log.(df.close) .- lag(log.(df.close))
```

and you can also do that in a `groupby` call so you don't have to manually identify the first observation for each security.